# Objective-c Norwegian alphabets æ ø å, NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: Issue

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have read
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5

But I did not find a solution to my problem.

I wrote:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

shows the sorted order A-Z with Æ and Å among A, Ø among O. 
It is supposed to be A-Z-Æ-Ø-Å, since I used *localized*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding the user's language for the entire application is generally not considered to be a good way to force the locale for a particular operation, as the user's preferences should determine how data is sorted.  If, for example, you have a language class or an otherwise intentionally-dual-language program), you might find it useful to the user to override the sorting order just for certain elements of the program.   Although it's a bit more work, if you need to make sure that the particular strings are always sorted in order for a particular locale, you should use the long form of the compare:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)range locale:(id)locale
```

You can get the locale for Norwegian by using the call:

```
NSLocale *noLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"no_NO"] autorelease];
```

So, you'd end up calling:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingComparator :^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSRange theRange = NSMakeRange( 0, [obj1 length]);
    return [obj1 compare: obj2 options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range: theRange locale: noLocale];
}];
```

This will not set the default language for the rest of the program, but it will explicitly use the specified locale in that particular comparison.

Comment: What does this method do? Change en to no permanently? Or temporarily? Right now I don't have computer, but I will check out your codes tomorrow. Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: I've edited my response to hopefully provide some clarification.   This makes the locale 'no', just for the particular comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by inserting this line in `-viewDidLoad` :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"no"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```